# Photoshop's shape properties for the polygon tool does not appear

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Why doesn't the properties panel in my design software show all the options for shapes? I was following a video tutorial on creating rounded corners, but I noticed that the panel offers more options for rectangles compared to polygons. I specifically want to create pointy stars, but I'm unable to find the supposed settings for it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I can't reproduce the problem unfortunately. Also tech support is generally off topic here.  I've seen this before though, can't remember when/where.  I wonder if you might consider [resetting your preferences](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/quick-tips-how-to-reset-photoshop-preferences/td-p/12502668).  Sorry can't really think of anything else.

Comment: You might also be able to remove the curves in the Polygon tool options along the top, by setting the curve to 0px, before you draw the shape. [see example](https://i.imgur.com/1pbdluU.png)

Comment: @BillyKerr polygons don't have anything to show on properties panel. You are right. before drawing the shape we have to put the input.

Comment: Normally though, you should be able to see the shape properties for a polygon, so that you can change them like a live shape. I don't know why it is missing. [see example](https://imgur.com/oLWCKry).

Comment: nah I dnt get anything when I draw polygon, only before drawing options pops up if I hit 'enter'.

Answer (score 2):

I can see *why*....

It's due to the **mask** on the shape layer. The Properties Panel is showing the *mask* properties rather than the *shape* properties.

I don't know how one works around this. Clearly the shape layer and *not* the mask is highlighted in the Layers panel. So.. the shape properties *should* be showing on the Properties Panel.

A simple solution would be to move the mask to a different layer, edit the shape properties and then put the mask back if you need it.

Comment: I can't actually reproduce this problem even if there is a mask on the shape layer. [See example](https://imgur.com/oLWCKry). Not sure what is going on here with the OPs example TBH. Could it be a bug, perhaps specific to a particular version of Photoshop CC? Or maybe it's new a feature? I'm not on the latest build, still on a 2021 version, which doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the "problem" either @BillyKerr - and I'm not using the "bleeding edbe" version here. It may indeed be a bug, or a prefs issues, or very localized.

Comment: @Scott I added some new images, Kindly check. each time I draw Polygon I nvr get anything in properties. But I get options when I draw rectangle.

Comment: I don't have the latest version installed.... I would **guess** one needs to click the "shape path" on the Properties Panel.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. In my case it was because I used ctrl + right click to modify the shape. In that moment the properties' *appearance* panel disappeared and then only *mask* is shown. When I tried to modify the shape in other ways there was no problem to modify it later.

Answer (score 0):

There's a gear icon at the top bar that you can configure to change the shape properties.[image]

The difference of access method might have to do with difference of the Photoshop's version being used.